# how to select dropdown on value option in ruby watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

**This is my drop down and i want to select it on its value option**

```
<select id ="">
<option value="01" title="  01 - Live animals">  01 - Live animals</option>
</select>
```

**I know that how to select drop down on its content i.e.**

```
ie.select_list(:id, "DropDownList_Product").select("01 - Live animals")
```

*actually I want to select drop down on its value 01,what should i have to do for that ?*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
ie.select_list(:id, "DropDownList_Product").select_value("01")
```

More information at http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Select#select_value-instance_method

Comment: @Željko Filipin how to do that using `PageObject gem`?